# Pyomo gams writer

Tags: pyomo, gams-math, scip

I have the following problem. I want to solve a number of MINLP's in the following manner:

1. Create .gms file using pyomo
2. Solve model on a server with the gams license and solver's like BARON and SCIP
3. Use the solution of the current MINLP for the next MINLP
4. Go to 1.

Now I have some questions:

1. What is the best way to read the solution of the previous MINLP (right now I'm reading the .dat file)
2. How can I change the default gams/mipstart option to a value of 3? (I tried: io_options['add_options']=['option gams/mipstart = 3;'] but didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the Pyomo/GAMS link.
But the "gams/mipstart = 3" line should go into a GAMS/SCIP options file (probably scip.opt, see also https://www.gams.com/25.1/docs/UG_SolverUsage.html#BASIC_USAGE_SOLVER_OPTION_FILE) and you would need to tell Pyomo to tell GAMS to use this option file.